# Caesar Cipher shift on new lines

Tags: python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I am having a problem with my code trying to do an advanced caesar cipher shift. I changed a certain letter to another, and then added a string to certain parts of a file before encoding, but am having problems doing the shifting now. This is my code:

```
import string
import sys
count = 1
cont_cipher = "Y"

#User inputs text
while cont_cipher == "Y":
    if count == 1:
        file = str(input("Enter input file:" ""))
        k = str(input("Enter shift amount: "))
        purpose = str(input("Encode (E) or Decode (D) ?: "))

    #Steps to encode the message, replace words/letter then shift        
        if purpose == "E":
            my_file = open(file, "r")
            file_contents = my_file.read()

            #change all "e"s to "zw"s 
            for letter in file_contents:
                if letter == "e":
                    file_contents = file_contents.replace(letter, "zw")

            #add "hokie" to beginning, middle, and end of each line
            lines = file_contents.split('\n')
            def middle_message(lines, position, word_to_insert):
                lines = lines[:position] + word_to_insert + lines[position:]
                return lines
            new_lines = ["hokie" + middle_message(lines[x], len(lines[x])//2, "hokie") + "hokie" for x in range(len(lines))]

        #math to do the actual encryption
        def caesar(word, shifts):
           word_list = list(new_lines)
           result = []
           s = 0
           for c in word_list:
               next_ord = ord(c) + s + 2
               if next_ord > 122:
                   next_ord = 97
               result.append(chr(next_ord))
               s = (s + 1) % shifts
           return "".join(result)

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            print(caesar(my_file, 5))

        #close file and add to count
        my_file.close()
        count = count + 1
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 58 found
```

I know that I need to split it into individual characters, but am not sure how to do this. I need to use the updated message and not the original file in this step...

Comment: `for c in word_list:` but word\_list contains strings (more then 1 character) instead of being a single string.  Did you mean to iterate over `word` instead?

Comment: I changed it to that instead, and now it doesn't print anything. Why is it not running through the  def caesar?

Comment: if you replace the file io with string literals you'd be able to run it through [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit), taking another look I think there is a number of things wrong with your code.